# can i find my wallet address without opening bitcoin core qt

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet.dat, mac

I havent ran bitcoin core qt for 4 years. And now the program wont run, just says bitcoin qt quit unexpectedly.

A: How can i check my bitcoin address and balance
B: How can i get the program working again.

driving me up the wall.

Comment: Might be answered here: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/7886/bitcoin-qt-v0-8-0b-client-on-mac-os-x-10-8-crashes-why Hopefully you have everything backed up?

Comment: To get helpful answers you should post as much potentially useful information as possible. What was your version of Bitcoin Core Qt?
You can easily check your adress' balance if you know the address on https://blockchain.info.